# Reducing memory and increasing speed while parsing XML files

Tags: c#, xml, performance, linq-to-xml, memory-consumption

I have a directory with about 30 randomly named XML files. So the name is no clue about their content. And I need to merge all of these files into a single file according to predefined rules. And unfortunately, it is too complex to use simple stylesheets.
Each file can have up to 15 different elements within its root. So, I have 15 different methods that each take an XDocument as parameter and search for a specific element in the XML. It will then process that data. And because I call these methods in a specific order, I can assure that all data is processed in the correct order.
Example nodes are e.g. a list of products, a list of prices for specific product codes, a list of translations for product names, a list of countries, a list of discounts on product in specific country and much, much more. And no, these aren't very simple structures either.

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
List<XmlFileData> files = ImportFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(f => new XDocument(f.FullName)).ToList();
files.ForEach(MyXml, FileInformation);
files.ForEach(MyXml, ParseComments);
files.ForEach(MyXml, ParsePrintOptions);
files.ForEach(MyXml, ParseTranslations);
files.ForEach(MyXml, ParseProducts);
// etc.
MyXml.Save(ExportFile.FullName);
```

I wonder if I can do this in a way that I have to read less in memory and generate a faster result. Speed is more important than memory, though. Thus, this solution works. I just need something faster that will use less memory.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you merging them in a way that they interleave or the root element from the next document starts immediately after the root element of the previous document closes?

Comment: They interleave. They can all contain bits of information and some of the information is duplicate information. (Which I have to check.)

Comment: Doh!  I figured they did, but was hoping they wouldn't.  How fast/slow is it running now?  What's your current memory usage?

Comment: Speed depends on the supplier of the data. One gets processed within seconds, the other takes over 5 minutes. Memory usage goes to around 1.5 GB but fortunately I use a 64-bit system. The slower files are about 350 MB in size and the resulting file is about the same size. (Basically, all the data gets merged.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create a separate `List<XElement>` for each of the different data types. For example:

```
List<XElement> Comments = new List<XElement>();
List<XElement> Options = new List<XElement>();
// etc.
```

Then for each document you can go through the elements in that document and add them to the appropriate lists. Or, in pseudocode:

```
for each document
    for each element in document
        add element to the appropriate list
```

This way you don't have to load all of the documents into memory at the same time. In addition, you only do a single pass over each document.

Once you've read all of the documents, you can concatenate the different elements into your single `MyXml` document. That is:

```
MyXml = create empty document
Add Comments list to MyXml
Add Options list to MyXml
// etc.
```

Another benefit of this approach is that if the total amount of data is larger than will fit in memory, those lists of elements could be files. You'd write all of the Comment elements to the Comments file, the Options to the Options file, etc. And once you've read all of the input documents and saved the individual elements to files, you can then read each of the element files to create the final XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your rules, and how interdependent the data is between the various files, you could probably process each file in parallel (or at least certain chunks of it).

Given that the XDocument's aren't being changed during the read, you could most certainly gather your data in parallel, which would likely offer a speed advantage.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You should examine the data you're loading in, and whether you can work on that in any special way to keep memory-usage low (and even gain some speed).