# How to get wcf message body using stream with less memory?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, .net-core

I have one xml file like this:

```xml
<bookstore>
<book genre='novel' ISBN='10-861003-324'><title>The Handmaid's Tale</title><price>19.95</price></book>
<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'><title>Pride And Prejudice</title><price>24.95</price></book>
</bookstore>
```

And I use this xml file to create one message. Then, I want to use stream to get the message body, so I used the code like this:

```cs
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("D:\\TestForCSharp\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\2books.xml");

Message message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null, xmlReader);
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
message.WriteBodyContents(writer);
writer.Flush();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

This already uses less memory than ReadOuterXml, but it increases the memory usage because of `message.WriteBodyContents(writer)`.

```cs
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("D:\\TestForCSharp\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\2books.xml");

Message message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, null, xmlReader);

XmlReader reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
string res = reader.ReadOuterXml();
Stream ms = GenerateStreamFromString(res);
```

```
public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Any better solution for the memory?

Is it possible to get the message body using stream without any memory cost?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the XmlTextReader can help you. XmlTextReader is a particular derivative for reading XML from text files.

And another answer [in this Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859206/reducing-memory-and-increasing-speed-while-parsing-xml-files) may help you.